# WPF DataGrid Border for Columns shifted

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, border

I am totally clueless which property is responsible for the shift of the vertical cell borders. The content is correctly aligned central, but the border seems to think its aligned right.

[image: DataGrid Example]

The XAML Definition is:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG_ComparedSet" 
          AllowDrop="True"
          Background="AliceBlue"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          PreviewDragEnter="File_DragEvent" 
          PreviewDragOver="File_DragEvent" 
          PreviewDrop="DG_ComparedSet_PreviewDrop">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Clear Comparison" Name="CXM_clearComparison" Click="CXM_clearComparison_Click" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

The programmatically built DataGrid layout is done by:

```
Style cellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
cellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily("Consolas")));
cellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));
cellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center));
cellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.MediumSeaGreen));

foreach (string colHead in parameters)
{
    DataGridTextColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn
    {
         Header = colHead,
         FontFamily = new FontFamily("Consolas"),
         Binding = new Binding(colHead),
         CellStyle = cellStyle
    };
    DG_ComparedSet.Columns.Add(col);
}
DG_ComparedSet.ItemsSource = dtOut.DefaultView;
```

Which property is missing or set incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Your settings for the cells' alignments is throwing off the rendering of the columns. Without seeing more of your code I cannot be sure of your intentions but if you want to have the cell text centered then center the content not the cell itself.

```
Style cellStyle = new Style (typeof (DataGridCell));
cellStyle.Setters.Add (new Setter (DataGridCell.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily ("Consolas")));
//cellStyle.Setters.Add (new Setter (DataGridCell.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));
//cellStyle.Setters.Add (new Setter (DataGridCell.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center));
cellStyle.Setters.Add (new Setter (TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Center));
cellStyle.Setters.Add (new Setter (DataGridCell.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.MediumSeaGreen));
```

that is assuming your cells contain text strings only of course.